# Add Unity-Tweak-Tool to the System-Settings on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, icons, system-settings, unity-tweak-tool

I have added the `unity-tweak-tools` to the `unity-control-center` as follows:

```
sudo gedit usr/share/applications/unity-tweak-tools
```

then completed the line `Categories=Settings;` as follows and added another line:

```
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;X-Unity-Settings-Panel;X-GNOME-PersonalSettings;
X-Unity-Settings-Panel=/usr/bin/unity-tweak-tools
```

It seems to work and the icon is getting shown up in the System Settings window, but after clicking it, nothing happens. Does anybody know the problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you named this with .desktop at the end of the file?  Have you also added the exec= line?